# wants to null values after api response is true

Tags: react-native

i want to clear my all text field when i post data to server and response become true here is my code of function where i post my data to API and its response exactly as i want but i want when response true all text field are clear..

```
updateProfile(){

axios.post( "http://172.104.217.178/api/update_sponsor_profile/"+this.state.UserId,{
  name:this.state.name,
  username:this.state.username,
  address:this.state.address,
  country_id:this.state.getCountryId,
  state_id:this.state.getStateId,
  city_id:this.state.getCityid,

} )
.then(response => {
alert(JSON.stringify(response));
if(response.data.status===1){

  this.setState({name:null,username:null,address:null,getCountryId:null,getStateId:null,getCityid:null})
}

})
.catch(error => alert(error.response.data));

}
```

here is the code of my text fields

```
 updateValue(text,field){
if(field==='name'){
  this.setState({name:text})
}
else if(field==='username'){
  this.setState({username:text})
}

else if(field==='address'){
  this.setState({address:text})
}
```

}

Comment: So what is the question here? Do you get any errors?

Comment: i dont get any error..i want only one thing when i post my data to server the values i enter in my text fields before data post become empty or in onther words i want my text fields empty after i post data on server

Comment: Can you post the code of your text fields? Or if they are the same just one of them.

Comment: check now.. i have update the question

Comment: If your `name` field takes its value from `state.name` this should work to update its value. Same goes for the rest of the fields. Did you try this and it didn't work?

Comment: yup i did but its not working

Comment: How do you set up your text fields? I mean the `jsx` code.

Comment: <Input  onChangeText={(text)=>this.updateValue(text,'address')}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you may clear your state correctly the input field doesn't take its value from your state, it just updates it when you input something so clearing the state doesn't affect it at all. Try setting the `Input` field like this:

```
<Input
    onChangeText={(text) => this.updateValue(text,'address')}
    value={this.state.address}
  />
```

the `value` prop is inheritted from the native `TextInput`, its documentation is [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput).